# Tomcat 7 : how to create virtual directory to store images?

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7

i need to create a folder out of webapp in tomcat to store images i upload from my Java EE web application and still the folder be accessible from the application.
I tried to add context to my server.xml :

```
<Context path="/images" docBase="C:/test/images/" />
```

but i get **404 not found** error when i try `http://localhost:8080/images`.
and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
please can somebody provide a step by step guide on how to do that, i'm sure it would help me and many others thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Comment: i'm using jsf primefaces `<p:fileupload>`, and it's working fine the probleme is where to upload the images.